# RSQlite parameterized query

Tags: r

I'd like to insert a value into a query without using paste() like this:

```
symbol<-'ES'
prices <- dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT * from fut_prices WHERE symbol LIKE '%:x%'", 
x=symbol)
```

The above is returning all the column names from fut_prices table but no rows. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(RSQLite)

con <- dbConnect(SQLite(), ":memory:")

DF <- data.frame(symbol = c("X", "ES"), price = 1:2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dbWriteTable(con, "DF", DF)

s <- "SELECT * from DF where symbol LIKE '%' || :x || '%'"
symbol <- "ES"
bind.data <- data.frame(x = symbol, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dbGetPreparedQuery(con, s, bind.data = bind.data)
```

giving:

```
  symbol price
1     ES     2
```